# Reply to a mail using gmail api ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, gmail-api

I am working on a Mailbox app I am trying to reply to a mail.

I had gone through the documentations.

```
 GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:nil];
query.message = gtlGmailMessage; //parent message
[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResult:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

I need to know what all changes I need to do in the gtlGmailMessage to reply to the parent mail.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *I had gone through the documentations* but you can't find how to reply email?

Comment: There is no specific documentation for GTLGmailQuery Class for iOS. If you find please let me know

Comment: So do I need to make a new GTLGmailMessage with same thread id with payload containing sender id and receiver id with a new body.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

We have to do all things with raw field.

```
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:nil];
NSString *strRaw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To:%@\nSubject:%@\nThreadId:%@\nReply-To:%@\n\n\n%@",strToBeRep,mail.subject,mail.threadId,strToBeRep,msgToBeSend];
NSData *messageBody = [strMessageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLGmailMessage *message =[[GTLGmailMessage alloc]init];
query.userId = @"me";
NSString *base64Encoded = [messageBody base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

message.raw = base64Encoded;

message.snippet = @"sadfasdfasd dafvasdvas dafvasdv";
base64Encoded = [base64Encoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"];
base64Encoded = [base64Encoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"-"];
message.threadId = self.mail.mail.threadId;
query.message = message;

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultForNewMessage:finishedWithObject:error:)];


- (void)displayResultForNewMessage:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailMessage *)emailsResponse error:(NSError *)error
{    
if(!error)
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```